# Scraping React charts in Python using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from a React chart on a website [Link](https://www.aholddelhaizepensioen.nl/over-ons/financiele-situatie/beleidsdekkingsgraad) using selenium. I'm able to locate the element, but not getting the data. The specific data I need from that chart resides within a nested series:

```
"data":[{"name":"December 2019",
            "....",
            "coverage":107.9}
```

within the element `<script id=react_5X8YGgN8H0GoMMQ4RLqjrQ </script>`

The final result should look like this, extracted from data.name and data.coverage:

```
months = [December 2019, Januari 2020, Februari 2020, etc.]
coverages = [107.9, 107.8, 107.2, etc.]
```

Some code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.aholddelhaizepensioen.nl/over-ons/financiele-situatie/beleidsdekkingsgraad'
website = url
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(website)
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_id("react_5X8YGgN8H0GoMMQ4RLqjrQ")
```

#### Solution 2

Since chitown88 states that the script tag is static, i.e. no need for selenium as requests can do the trick, here's another solution that got the data I need.

```
import requests
import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import pandas as pd

# Fetch site data
url = 'https://www.aholddelhaizepensioen.nl/over-ons/financiele-situatie/beleidsdekkingsgraad'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs4(r.content, 'html.parser')

# Find script
script_data = soup.find('script', attrs={'id':'react_5X8YGgN8H0GoMMQ4RLqjrQ'})
script_to_string = str(script) # cast to string for regex

# Regex
coverage_pattern = r'(?<="coverage":)\d{2,3}.\d{1}' #positive lookup, find everything after "coverage": with 2 or 3 numbers, a dot, and another number
months_pattern = r'(?<="name":")\w+\s\d{4}' #same as coverage_pattern, now based on word followed by four digits

# Data
coverages = re.findall(coverage_pattern,script_to_string)
months = re.findall(months_pattern,scrip_to_string)
frame = pd.DataFrame({'months':months,'coverages':coverages})
```

Comment: There are couple elements with the same `id`. You select `div`. Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//script[@id='react_5X8YGgN8H0GoMMQ4RLqjrQ']")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no need to use selenium as the data is embedded in the script tags of the static response. Just need to pull it out, manipulate the string a bit to get into json format, then read that in. Then just a matter of iterating through it:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.aholddelhaizepensioen.nl/over-ons/financiele-situatie/beleidsdekkingsgraad'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'coverage' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text
        break

jsonStr = jsonStr.split('Section, ')[-1]

loop = True
while loop == True:
    try:
        jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr + '}')
        loop = False
    except:
        jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit('}',1)[0]
 
data = jsonData['data']['data']
months = []
coverages = []

for each in data:
    months.append(each['name'])
    coverages.append(each['coverage'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(months)
['December 2019', 'Januari 2020', 'Februari 2020', 'Maart 2020', 'April 2020', 'Mei 2020', 'Juni 2020', 'Juli 2020', 'Augustus 2020', 'September 2020', 'Oktober 2020', 'November 2020']
```

and

```
print(coverages)
[107.9, 107.8, 107.2, 106.1, 105.1, 104.3, 103.7, 103.0, 102.8, 102.3, 101.9, 101.6]
```

Comment: I accepted your answer as a solution since it guided me to the right direction. Thank you for that. However in my original question I added another solution, which is less extensive in code and results in the same outcome. So others can pick the solution they like if they encounter a similar problem.